# How to tap on a specific point using Xcode UITests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane-snapshot

I want to use Xcode UI tests with the [Fastlane Snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot) to make screenshots of the Cordova app. Basically, as my entire app is just a web view, all the Xcode UI test helper methods become irrelevant, and I just want to tap on specific points, e.g. `tap(x: 10, y: 10)` should produce a tap at the point `{10px; 10px}`.

That's probably very simple, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can tap a specific point with the [`XCUICoordinate` API](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUICoordinate.html). Unfortunately you can't just say "tap 10,10" referencing a pixel coordinate. You will need to create the coordinate with a relative offset to an actual view.

We can use the mentioned web view to interact with the relative coordinate.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let webView = app.webViews.element
let coordinate = webView.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10))
coordinate.tap()
```

---

Side note, but have you tried interacting with the web view directly? I've had a lot of success using `app.links["Link title"].tap()` or `app.staticTexts["A different link title"].tap()`. [Here's a demo app I put together demonstrating interacting with a web view.](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet#tapping-links-in-web-views)

---

**Update**: As Michal W. pointed out in the comments, you can now tap a coordinate *directly*, without worrying about normalizing the offset.

```
let normalized = webView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
let coordinate = normalized.withOffset(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10))
coordinate.tap()
```

Notice that I pass 0,0 to the normalized vector and then the actual point, 10,10, to the second call.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct as I needed to add 'coordinateWithOffset' to perform x/y tap:

let cooridnate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)).coordinateWithOffset(CGVector(dx: position.x, dy: position.y))  
        cooridnate.tap()   
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13373

Comment: Good idea! Thanks @MichałW. I noted the comment in an update to the answer as it was already accepted.

Comment: Another small optimization is to use `CGVector.zero` instead of `CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)`.

Answer (score 23):

@joe To go a little further off of Joe Masilotti's approach I put mine in an `extension`and gave prepositional phrases to the global and local params.

```
func tapCoordinate(at xCoordinate: Double, and yCoordinate: Double) {
    let normalized = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
    let coordinate = normalized.withOffset(CGVector(dx: xCoordinate, dy: yCoordinate))
    coordinate.tap()
}
```

By giving the global an identifiable name I can easily understand the instance for example:

```
tapCoordinate(at x: 100, and y: 200)
```

Comment: Worked for me in Swift 3!

Comment: This doesn't compile in Swift 3

Comment: I had to run it as `tapCoordinate(at:100, and:200)` and it worked perfectly! Unlike the exact example you used which didn't compile in Swift 5

Answer (score 12):

I found Laser's answer to work fine with Xcode 11, but made a few tweaks to easily integrate it into my testing.

```
extension XCUIApplication {
    func tapCoordinate(at point: CGPoint) {
        let normalized = coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero)
        let offset = CGVector(dx: point.x, dy: point.y)
        let coordinate = normalized.withOffset(offset)
        coordinate.tap()
    }
}
```

Now, when I need to tap on a given location, I just provide a `CGPoint` and call this against my `XCUIApplication` like so:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: xCoord, y: yCoord)
app.tapCoordinate(at: point)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<something>.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector.zero).withOffset(CGVector(dx:10,dy:60)).tap()
```

Pass .zero to the normalized vector and then the actual point (10,60)

Comment: This is great for Swift 4 :)