# Handler of addUIInterruptionMonitor is not called for Alert related to Photos

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

```
private func acceptPermissionAlert() {
    
    _ = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "") { alert -> Bool in
        
        if alert.buttons["Don’t Allow"].exists { //doesnt get here second time
            
            alert.buttons.element(boundBy: 1).tapWhenExists()
            
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }
}
```

and this doesn't work for:

[image]

In the beginning of the app, it works perfect while accepting permission for notifications, but here, it doesn't work. Why is this?

Answer (score 26):

I'vs found that `addUIInterruptionMonitor` sometimes doesn't handle an alert in time, or until tests have finished. If it isn't working, try using Springboard, which manages the iOS home screen. You can access alerts, buttons, and more from there, and this is particularly useful for tests where you know exactly when an alert will show.

So, something like this:

```
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard") 

let alertAllowButton = springboard.buttons.element(boundBy: 1)
if alertAllowButton.waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
   alertAllowButton.tap()
}
```

The `buttons.element(boundBy:1)` will ensure you tap the button on the right, change 1 to 0 to tap the left, (because sometimes the ' in `"Don't Allow"` causes a problem).

Comment: The `addUIInterruptionMonitor` worked locally but on CI failed to trigger for access to camera. This was the only approach that seems to work.

Comment: @possen
  THAT is true, `addUIInterruptionMonitor` just failed our tests on CI. I have replaced it with springboard too, and it fixes the failure on CI.

Comment: great to hear :) @Bartłomiej Semańczyk I hope this fixed your issue?

Comment: Not working anymore on iOS 15.2 or 15.4.

Comment: Still works for me in 15.5, but is unreliable as well.

Answer (score 22):

Add:

```
app.tap()
```

at the end of the method.

> This is because you need to interact with the app for the handler to fire.

Comment: or app.swipeUp() if tapping would cause something to actually happen in your app (and you don't want it to)

Comment: It works for me. This is kind of weird...
"you need to interact with the app for the handler to fire."
is that somewhere documented?

Comment: is there a radar for this bug?

Comment: `app.tap()` taps to the middle of the screen, which might result in unwanted actions, as @xaphod pointed out. If you cannot use `swipeUp()` either, maybe you can tap to a specific point on the screen, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36287500/1987726)

Comment: Related : https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/82#issue-262034541

Comment: Add this, but handler is still not triggered on Alert action sheet.

Comment: Any interaction performed could trigger the handler, not just `app`. The key is: the handler would not be automatically triggered on the alert popping up. The handler will run only when the alert pops up AND after you fail to interact with some element.

Answer (score 13):

After adding the interruption monitor, you should continue to interact with the app as if it has not appeared.

*Also note that you have a 'smart quote' in your button identifier, instead of a regular apostrophe.*

```
let photosAlertHandler = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Photo Permissions") { alert -> Bool in
    if alert.buttons["Don't Allow"].exists {
        alert.buttons.element(boundBy: 1).tapWhenExists()
        return true
    }
    return false
}

// Do whatever you want to do after dismissing the alert
let someButton = app.buttons["someButton"]
someButton.tap() // The interruption monitor's handler will be invoked if the alert is present
```

When the next interaction happens after the alert appears, the interruption monitor's handler will be invoked and the alert will be handled.

You should also remove the interruption monitor when you think you're done with it, otherwise it will be invoked for any other alerts that appear.

```
removeUIInterruptionMonitor(photosAlertHandler)
```

Comment: The actual button has the 'smart quote' character `’` not `'`. Also your code produces the compiler error *Value of type 'XCUIElement' has no member 'tapWhenExists'*.

Comment: @AaronBrager the `tapWhenExists()` method is one from the question's code, not a standard library function. I suggest you use `tap()` instead, wrapped in a check for `exists`.

Comment: "When the next interaction happens", upvote from me for that one

Comment: "When the next interaction happens" is indeed the key takeaway for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case the suggested solutions don't work on iOS 17+, I found a [workaround](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737880?answerId=770725022#770725022). In this snippet I have 4 different permissions, one of them is location, which has a different button name.

```swift
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
for i in 0..<4 {
    let allowLocationButton = springboard.buttons["Allow While Using App"]
    let allowButton = springboard.buttons["Allow"]
            
    if allowLocationButton.isHittable {
        allowLocationButton.tap()
    } else if allowButton.isHittable {
        allowButton.tap()
    } else {
        break
    } 
}
```