# XCUI Test: app.debugDescription shows info of the last screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automated-tests, xcode-ui-testing

When I execute the command

```
(lldb) po app.debugDescription
```

it displays the details from the last view. 
How do I refresh it to show the new element tree??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view hierarchy will refresh when you interact with the app (since it's reasonable to expect that the app's state doesn't change unless the user interacts with it).

To get a fresh view hierarchy, you can either tap on the app: `app.tap()` and then print the debug description, or you could create a new instance of `XCUIApplication` and use that instead of the existing `app` property which has the cached view hierarchy. The new instance should show a fresh view hierarchy.

Comment: Yep, give it a try :)

Comment: I tried, and it works. But if there is an alertwindow and we press tap, it gets cancelled. I want to see the details of the alert view, but the details of the old screen are shown. Any ideas??

Comment: You can print out a property of an XCUIElementQuery like count to force a fresh snapshot of the view hierarchy. For example just print `app.alerts.count`

Comment: @Vinayaka to interact with an alert, use an interruption monitor as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973904/handler-of-adduiinterruptionmonitor-is-not-called-for-alert-related-to-photos/39976352#39976352

Comment: @Vinayaka alerts get automatically cancelled by XCTest if you don't handle them yourself, that's why you're seeing it get cancelled. :)