# How to tap on a specific point on Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I work with swift's UI testing, and I need to be able to tap a specific point on my app. I followed the answers from [How to tap on a specific point using Xcode UITests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285090/how-to-tap-on-a-specific-point-using-xcode-uitests), which worked great for testing on iPad. However, when doing the same on the simulator nothing happens. No errors, the program simply acts like I'm pressing *something*, but not anything in particular, and the program can't continue executing since the right info isn't there.

Is this possibly a local problem? If not, what can I do to tap at specific coordinates on the simulator?

Comment: (1) I believe the short answer is - you can't. It's a simulator! To "tap" you "click". How do you tap on a specific point on a real device? Short answer? You don't. You *record* the specific point that *was* tapped. Same with the simulator. Anything otherwise is illogical. (2) That said, what *exactly* are you trying to do? Test something? As it is, your question is somewhat vague. If all you wish to do is test some code where a specific point is "tapped" - which is all you've said - then "hard-code" it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot just tap a screen. You have to tap on something.

Easiest thing to do would be tapping using elements in app and method `coordinate(withNormalizedOffset:)` from Apple.

Create a method, thats gonna have input parameters element (you want to tap on) and offset (the point, you want to tap on). Something like this:

```
func tap(on element: XCUIElement, xOffset: Double, yOffset: Double) {
    let coordinate = element.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: xOffset, dy: yOffset))

    if element.waitForExistence(5) {
         coordinate.tap()
    }
}
```

You can then tap on any element within the tested app by calling this method and giving it the element.

F.e.: 
You want to tap on some point in app itself with `0.8` and `0.5` offset:

`tap(on: XCUIApplication(), xOffset: 0.8, yOffset: 0.5)`