# How to simulate left right tap of a UIPageControl in iOS UI Test?

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, uipagecontrol

I have a page control that spans the whole width of the screen. When tapping on the left side, the `valueChanged` function is called, and `pageControl.currentPage` is less one less. When tapping on the right side, the opposite happens. How do I simulate the tap to the left or right in UI Test?

```
let pc = XCUIApplication().pageIndicators["pageControl"]
pc.tap() // cannot specify left or right hand tap
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36285090/3151675

Answer (score 0):

You should change the X offset of the tap. The easiest way to get the right half of a standard `UIPageControl` is getting its width and subtracting 1 from it.

```
func tapPageControl(isRightTap: Bool) {
    let pageControl = XCUIApplication().pageIndicators["pageControl"]
    let xOffset = isRightTap ? pageControl.frame.width - 1 : 0
    let coordinate = pageControl.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero).withOffset(CGVector(dx: xOffset, dy: 0))
    coordinate.tap()
}
```