# How tap by x and y coordinates iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

For Android world, we could tap any locations in by:

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
device.click(x, y)
```

And the `x` and `y` above could be get from Pixelmator like:

[image]

For example, the coordinate of key `a` should be `x=100` and `y=1800` (Ruler from Pixelmator).

According to [tapCoordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43009687/1319619) , we might do something similar in iOS:

```
func tapCoordinate(at xCoordinate: Double, and yCoordinate: Double) {
    let normalized = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
    let coordinate = normalized.withOffset(CGVector(dx: xCoordinate, dy: yCoordinate))
    coordinate.tap()
}
```

But it didn't work as expected, I was wondering if maybe we could tap some points by the `x` and `y` of the global screen?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you appear to be using **pixel** coordinates. You should't do that. Apple uses points (72nds of an inch) as its coordinate system. Devices with retina displays may have 2 or 3 pixels per point. You need to figure out the pixels per point for your test device and divide pixel coordinates by that value to get coordinates in points, and use those point values instead of pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. The function `debugDescription()` generates a string from various data types, suitable for logging to the console. iOS doesn't "calculate the coordinates from debugDescription".

You don't tell us what you are logging. You should edit your question to tell us what it is that you are logging, show the code that captures the value, and also show the print statement that logs it.

Based on the format of the output, it looks like you are logging a rectangle (`CGRect` data type.)

A `CGRect` is in the form (origin, size), where `origin` is a `CGPoint` and size is a `CGSize`.

It sounds like `tapCoordinate` is giving your the center of the rectangle, which would be:

```
x = rect.origin.x + size.width/2
y = rect.origin.y + size.width/2
```

That gives

```
x = 23+41/2 = 43.5
y = 573+49/2 = 597.5
```

Assuming your x value is a typo and should be 33, that is quite close to the values you give in your question.